# Filling a model with a list from Textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Now I do not really understand you. Sorry, I just started this whole study not so long ago. I’ll try to explain again what I can’t do.
I have an empty object and an object with data with the same structure.

```
data: [
        {id: 1, title: "title1"},
        {id: 2, title: "title1"},
        {id: 3, title: "title3"},
        {id: 4, title: "title4"},
        {id: 5, title: "title3"}
      ],

item: [
        {
          itemId: "",
          itemname: ""
        }
      ]
```

And I have select and textarear. Select have data, textarear empty. Textarear displays title.

I want to press a button. Selected item from select. copied to textarear (title only), and also itemId - this selected element id: 5 and itemname - the same title: "title3" element, was recorded in item [].

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-hermann-g9flw

Comment: What do you exactly mean by transforming values to model? can you add more details?

Comment: Are you trying to populate the textarea with the selected index?

Comment: I mean. that you need to fill in the object (item: [{) that I described. when transferring values from select in taxtarear.

Comment: your question is not clearly explain the problem but I guess that your handler function is written for general all events ( which create one function for handle all events) and this situation case an unclearly way for you to manage put your data in the state.

Comment: I corrected my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do check now

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      id: null,
      title: "",
      filmItem: "",
      listFilms: [],
      data: [
        { id: 1, title: "title1" },
        { id: 2, title: "title2" },
        { id: 3, title: "title3" },
        { id: 4, title: "title4" }
      ],
      item: []
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onChangeArea = this.onChangeArea.bind(this);
    this.addFilm = this.addFilm.bind(this);
    this.choice = this.choice.bind(this);
  }

  addFilm(film) {
    const selectedData = this.state.data.find(item => item.id == film);
    console.log(selectedData);
    this.setState({
      listFilms: [...this.state.listFilms, selectedData.title],
      item: [
        ...this.state.item,
        { itemId: selectedData.id, itemname: selectedData.title }
      ]
    });
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onChangeArea = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value.split("\n") });
  };

  choice(title) {
    this.setState({ filmItem: title });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="row App-main">
          <div>
            <select name="filmItem" size="4" onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}>
              {this.state.data.map(film => (
                <option key={film.title} value={film.id}>
                  {film.title}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button
              className="editButton"
              onClick={() => this.addFilm(this.state.filmItem)}
            >
              button
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <textarea
              name="films"
              onChange={this.onChangeArea}
              value={this.state.listFilms.map(r => r).join("\n")}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="text-input" onChange={this.onChange} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <pre style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: but how to convey the whole object through select and not the only title

Comment: @Denis please do check now